# Filtrar datos de un campo foráneo en Django

Tags: python, django, mvc

Estoy construyendo un listado de Expedientes con una tabla que almacena el Id del Expediente y la CURP del paciente (Este último una llave foránea referenciada a la tabla pacientes).
Tengo mi vista de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento solo realizo filtrados a partir de la llave primaria (Id_Exped), como se muestra a continuación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, necesito ahora filtrar la búsqueda por medio de la CURP.
El código de mi Model es el siguiente:

```
from django.db import models
from ..models import pacientes, expedientes
from django import forms

class expedientes_model():
    def expedientes_list(filtrarexpediente):
        if filtrarexpediente == None:
            expedientesvar = expedientes.objects.order_by("CURP_id")
        else:
        expedientesvar = expedientes.objects.filter(Id_Exped__contains=filtrarexpediente)
    return expedientesvar

    def getexpediente(Id_Exped):
        expedientemost = expedientes.objects.get(Id_Exped=Id_Exped)
        return expedientemost

class RegistrarExpediente(forms.Form):
    CURP = forms.CharField(label= 'CURP del Paciente', required=True)
```

El código de mi Controller es el siguiente:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from App.Models.ExpedientesModel import expedientes_model, RegistrarExpediente
from ..models import expedientes, pacientes
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

class ExpedientesController():
    @login_required
    def index(request):
        filtrarexpediente = None
        if request.method == "POST":
            filtrarexpediente = request.POST.get('filtrarexpediente')
        expedientes_list = expedientes_model.expedientes_list(filtrarexpediente)
        paginator = Paginator(expedientes_list,6) #El segundo parametro corresponde a cuántos items se desea ver
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            items = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            items = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context_exped = {'expedientes_list': items}
    return render(request, 'views/expedientes/expedientes.html', context_exped)

def details(request,Id_Exped):
    objects = expedientes_model.getexpediente(Id_Exped)
    context_exped = {'expediente': objects}
    return render(request, 'views/expedientes/detailsexped.html', context_exped)

def registrarexpediente(request):
    dataCURP = None
    template = 'views/expedientes/registrarexpediente.html'
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrarExpediente(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            CURP = form.cleaned_data.get('CURP')
            CURPexped = expedientes.objects.filter(CURP = CURP)
            for item in CURPexped:
                dataCURP = item.CURP
            if dataCURP != None:
                context_exped = {'form': form, 'error':'El paciente ya cuenta con expediente registrado.'}
                return render(request, template, context_exped)
            else:
                CURP = form.cleaned_data.get('CURP')
                #NewExpediente = expedientes(CURP=CURP)
                #NewExpediente.save()
                NewExpediente = expedientes()
                NewExpediente.CURP = pacientes.objects.get(CURP = request.POST['CURP'])
                NewExpediente.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('expedientes')
        else:
            context_exped = {'form': form}
            return render(request, template, context_exped)
    else:
        context_exped = {'form': RegistrarExpediente()}
        return render(request, template, context_exped)
```

Si modifico en getexpediente Id_Exped por CURP_id para filtrar por la CURP, me salta el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia u observación de que estoy realizando mal?
¿Cómo puedo obtener el filtrado por la CURP y no por el ID?

Gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: Creo que no he entendido bien lo que preguntas. ¿Quieres buscar por un objeto CURP y no por un ID?

Comment: Comparte tus modelos, por favor.

Comment: Si, mi intención es buscar por medio de la llave foránea CURP_id.
Pd: Ya está actualizada la publicación con los Modelos.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que no puedo hacer comentarios todavía te recomiendo por acá varias cosas entre ellas dale una leída al libro de django lo puedes buscar en google y es gratis esto te dará mejores bases en todo el conjunto del framework lo segundo es que también leas los estilos de programación pep8 con el fin de que tengas un estilo predefinido para que todos los desarrolladores puedan entender mejor tu código quizá no resuelva puntualmente tu pregunta pero de manera indirecta te podras dar cuenta de lo que te está faltando y podrás mejorar en el uso del framework. Saludos!